SpringBoot PrimeFaces page is blank
I have a spring boot primefaces hello world project:
primefaces-demo
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── primefacesdemo
│   │   │               ├── MySpringBootApplication.java
│   │   │               └── HelloWorld.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       ├── META-INF
│   │       │   └── resources
│   │               └── index.xhtml
├── pom.xml

and here is my bean class:
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;
@Named(value = "HelloWorld")
@ViewScoped
public class HelloWorld{
    public String message = "Hello, PrimeFaces!";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}

and my index.xhtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <title>Hello World with PrimeFaces</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel header="Hello World">
            <h:outputText value="#{HelloWorld.message}" />
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>

and my dependencies:
<!-- Spring Boot Starter Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- PrimeFaces -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>14.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jakarta Faces API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jakarta Faces Implementation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jakarta Inject API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jakarta CDI API -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Spring Boot DevTools -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

I'm using java 17 and Spring boot version 3.2.2.
When i launch my app using the maven command: mvn spring-boot:run, and then i access to the : http://localhost:8080/index.xhtml, it shows me a blank page.
I did not configur the web.xml page because spring configure it automatically and for the faces-config.xml, i did not use it because it is a hello world project.

Update:

I added this class:
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet;

@Configuration
public class JsfConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> facesServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean<FacesServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new FacesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return registration;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // This will set the project stage to Development
        System.setProperty("javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE", "Development");
    }
}

and here is my new pom.xml file:
    <dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- PrimeFaces and Jakarta EE dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Thymeleaf extras for Jakarta -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    
    <!-- Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-el-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

and now, it shows me this error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory
jakarta.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.


Just use JoinFaces and save yourself the trouble: http://joinfaces.org/

@Melloware Actually i only need to understand why it is not working !

There is e.g. no ViewScoped available in Spring.
jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped is CDI, that wont work without writing many code or just use joinfaces.
